# angularjs ui-router : How to change state or page from inside controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using Angularjs and Ui-router. I am able to call the pages with ui-sref from HTML. I want to call for a new page from controller when using ui-router. How to do you do it.  I have given the code below.

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    home: {
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    }
  }
})

  $stateProvider.state('results', {
  url: '/results',
  views: {
    results: {
      templateUrl: 'results.html'
    }
  }
})

$stateProvider.state('help', {
  url: '/help',
  views: {
    help: {
      templateUrl: 'help.html'
    }
  }
})
})
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller ("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.devList1 = [
    {text:'Most Accurate', checked: false},
    {text:'Accurate', checked: false}, 
    {text:'Neutral', checked: false},
    {text:'Inaccurate', checked: false},
    {text:'Most Inaccurate', checked: false}];
    $scope.indexToShow = 0;
    $scope.questionlist = ["one", "two" , "three", "four", "five"];

     $scope.imChanged = function(isChecked, index){      
             angular.forEach($scope.devList1, function (items) {
                items.checked= false;
            });
            $scope.devList1[index].checked=true;
            $scope.okaychecked = true;
        }
    $scope.nextquestion =  function(){
        $scope.okaychecked = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.devList1, function (items) {
                items.checked= false;
            });
        if (($scope.indexToShow) < ($scope.questionlist.length - 1)){
            $scope.indexToShow = ($scope.indexToShow + 1) % $scope.questionlist.length;
            }
        else {
            $state.go('home',"");

        }
        }
    })
```

and html below

```
 <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller = "mainCtrl">


<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
</ion-nav-bar>


  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive" tabs-icon-top>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-help" ui-sref="help">
      <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <ion-view title="Single">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <h2>Single Construct</h2>
      <p>Here Single Constructs.</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="results.html">
  <ion-view title="Results">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <p>Results here</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="help.html" >
  <ion-view title="Multiple">

      <ion-content padding = "true">      
        <div class="card"> 
            <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in questionlist track by $index" ng-show="$index == indexToShow">
                    {{item}}
                </div>          
        </div>
        <ion-checkbox  ng-repeat="items in devList1" ng-model="items.checked"  ng-change="imChanged(items.checked, $index)" ng-value = "items">{{items.text}}
            </ion-checkbox>
        <div  ng-show="okaychecked">
            <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-positive" ng-click = "nextquestion()" >NEXT</a>
        </div>
        </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hv to call the state change or call new page at 
 `$state.go('results',"");` position. How do you do it.

`$state.go` don't seem to work. I want to go to results page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$state.go('results');` in stead of `$state.go('results', "");`. The second field is for setting the options of the `$state.go` method. I guess it's not working because you leave this as an empty string. If you don't put anything there, it will use the default values.

Comment: I have tried that also, but it is not working. The view is still in the help page. Is the way I define correct. I don't know where i am making mistake

Comment: Could you put a console.log("test"); message in your method that you are calling? That way we can check wether or not the method is being called.

Comment: method is being called, I put a alert and it gets called. The problem is in $state.go.

Comment: Console.log(''test") gives Error: $state is not defined

Comment: Then you have to inject '$state' into your controller '.controller ("mainCtrl", function($scope, $state)'

Comment: The $state error is solved.I get the 'test' in the console log output, but the result page is not  loading

Comment: The results page is loading,but it is still showing contents of help page. Thankyou for taking me across this hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject `$state` in your controller

```
.controller ("mainCtrl", function($scope, $state) {
```

Then, you can use it

```
$state.go('results');
```